# Will Apple reject my application if it does not run on an iPad 1?

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm a beginner programmer and I have a universal application that works perfectly on iPhone and iPad with IOS 6.0 and up. However, it has certain features which cannot run on an iPad 1 because this device can only upgrade up to IOS 5.1.1. Whenever I run on an iPad 5.1 simulator, the application crashes. This is not the problem since I already expect it to do that.

Will Apple reject my application since it does not run on the iPad 1? Are there other iPad applications that leave out iPad 1's?

Comment: You'll be fine - sometimes you need features that were introduced in a newer version.

Comment: ... just make sure you set the deployment target to 6.0. If you claim your app works on 5 and it doesn't then that's another question again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course not! Obviously, Apple thinks iPad 1 owners should just buy new iPads. :)

BTW, you should check out Apple's page on the [approval process](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/index.html)
, especially their [approval guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html) for information on what they are looking for in an app submission.

Answer (score 1):

No, they will not. So long as your app is supported on the latest iOS version, they will not reject your app for not supporting older devices. If your app has additional hardware requirements that the latest OS does not, be sure to clearly specify this in your app description.